# Connecting Existing PostgreSQL 28p01: password autentication faild for user "postgres"

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, webapi, postgresql-12

Database-First for existing Postgresql to run this do
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=localhost;Database=mydb;Username=postgres;Password=Hi$22222" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL have an error 28p01: password autentication faild for user "postgres"
for building dotnet core 3.1 webAPI

Comment: I run the code above on VS code PowerShell terminal to connect the existing structured PostgreSQL with my Dotnet core 3.1 web API

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear: you did not provide the correct password. But unrelated to that: you should **not** use the superuser for your application. Create  a regular user (without "superuser" rights) and use _that_ from within your application.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this type of error by giving my password using character and underscore only previously I use special character $. That is it and it's work for me.